# SwiftUI - Determining Current Device and Orientation

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to detect when the device is on iPad and in Portrait.

Currently I use the `UIDevice` API in UIKit and use an environment object to watch changes. I use the solution found here - [Determining Current Device and Orientation](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126878).

However the `orientationInfo.orientation` is initially always equal to `.portrait` until rotated into portrait and then back to landscape.

So when doing the following to display the `FABView`

```
struct HomeView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var orientationInfo: OrientationInfo
let isPhone = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone

    var body: some View {
      ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
          #if os(iOS)
          if isPhone == false && orientationInfo.orientation == .portrait {
            FABView()
          }
          #endif
      }
    }
}
```

The view is loaded when the iPad is initially in landscape, but when changing to portrait and back to landscape is then removed. Why is this happening and how can I make sure the view isn't loaded on first load ?

**Full Code**

```
struct HomeTab: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(OrientationInfo())
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var orientationInfo: OrientationInfo
let isPhone = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone

    var body: some View {
      ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
          #if os(iOS)
          if isPhone == false && orientationInfo.orientation == .portrait {
            FABView()
          }
          #endif
      }
    }
}

final class OrientationInfo: ObservableObject {
    enum Orientation {
        case portrait
        case landscape
    }
    
    @Published var orientation: Orientation
    
    private var _observer: NSObjectProtocol?
    
    init() {
        // fairly arbitrary starting value for 'flat' orientations
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            self.orientation = .landscape
        }
        else {
            self.orientation = .portrait
        }
        
        // unowned self because we unregister before self becomes invalid
        _observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [unowned self] note in
            guard let device = note.object as? UIDevice else {
                return
            }
            if device.orientation.isPortrait {
                self.orientation = .portrait
            }
            else if device.orientation.isLandscape {
                self.orientation = .landscape
            }
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        if let observer = _observer {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` for detecting orientation changes but you shouldn't rely on it when the app starts.

`UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation` will be false at the beginning and therefore both

- `UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape`

and

- `UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait`

will return `false`.

Instead you can use `interfaceOrientation` from the first window scene:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPortrait = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("isPortrait: \(String(isPortrait))")
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene else { return }
                self.isPortrait = scene.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait
            }
    }
}
```

Also note that *device orientation* is not equal to *interface orientation*. When the device is upside down in portrait mode, device orientation is *portrait* but interface orientation can be *landscape* as well.

I think it's better to rely on the interface orientation in your case.

Comment: Excellent solution. I'd only add that, if you want to know the interface orientation on launch, without waiting for a rotation to occur, it's possible to add the same code to .onAppear

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another details that can help in some cases:

You can get orientation by rawValue:

```
UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue
```

- Portrait = 1
- PortraitUpSideDown = 2
- LandscapeLeft = 3 (Top of the Device go left)
- LandscapeRight = 4 (Top of the Device go right)

What is often forgotten is that there is also a Flat orientation. This can be an issue when you test your app on the physical device.

- Flat = 5 (Device is on the back)
- Flat = 6 (Device is on the front/screen)

This is important when you use Notification for `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification.`

Because you will get notification every time user change Flat orientation, but you expected only to get notified when it goes from Portrait to Landscape and vice versa.

**Solutions to this problem**

1. You can use **.isValidInterfaceOrientation** which returns only Portrait and Landscape orientations.

`UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation`

2. You can change var only when **rawValue** is from 1...4

   ```
   struct ContentView: View {
       @State private var isPortrait = false

       var body: some View {
           Text("isPortrait: \(String(isPortrait))")
               .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in

                   if UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue <= 4 { // This will run code only on Portrait and Landscape changes
                       guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene else { return }
                       self.isPortrait = scene.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait
                   }
               }
       }
   }
   ```