# horizontalSizeClass returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make my swiftUI view resize dynamically.
I see that the way to do this is to use the environment info like below:

```
@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass
```

However, it does not seem to return anything.
When using the debugger, I see that the variable is set to 'nil'.
What am I doing wrong? Do I need to enable an option or something in info.plist for example?

My code is pretty basic:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass

    var body: some View {
        if self.sizeClass == .compact {
            Home_Vertical()
                
        }
        else {
            Home_Horizontal()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm developing for iPhone and allowed all device orientations.
The iOS deployment  target is iOS 14.0 and xCode's version is 12.3.

Comment: have you ever found answer to your question? I have the same issue in one project. And the same SwiftUI preview is working fine in freshly created sample.. Also other properties from SwiftUI.Environment are working fine, but size classes are nil.

Comment: No, I just disabled reorientation... I'll have to check if the latest updates helped or not.

Answer (score 2):

Size classes work differently than orientations.

For example, for iPhone 12 Pro you have two combinations:

- when `orientation: vertical` -> `verticalSizeClass: regular`, `horizontalSizeClass: compact`
- when `orientation: horizontal` -> `verticalSizeClass: compact`, `horizontalSizeClass: compact`

Which means that for most iPhones `@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass` will always be `compact` regardless of the orientation.

In general you should design your views against size classes and not device orientation.

However, if you really want to change views depending on the orientation you can subscribe to `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` as explained here:

- [SwiftUI - Determining Current Device and Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65586833/8697793)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look into it. As for the sizeClass, while it's about the orientation, I'm more interested in knowing if we have a compact view or not. In my case, it's not returning .compact all the time, it's returning "nil".

Answer (score 0):

It is optional by interface declaration (see below), so it is "by design" - it means system might not detected yet size class, and it will be updated later. You should handle such case explicitly to whatever appropriate to your app.

```
extension EnvironmentValues {

    /// The horizontal size class of this environment.
    @available(macOS, unavailable)
    @available(tvOS, unavailable)
    @available(watchOS, unavailable)
    public var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
```

Comment: I'm using iOS and it should be available there. Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your answer. Would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass)` was returning `nil` when declared on the `App` and consumed within the `WindowGroup`. After moving the environment var to a root view, it returns the proper values.